# onBackPressed() to parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parent-child, parent

I have an app with lots of activities. In an activity, I want to go back to the parent activity when I press the back button. (The previous activity and the parent activity are not the same). How can I do this with onBackPressed? 
Thanks is advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [this page about navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp) from the documentation. Here's what they have to say:

> To navigate up when the user presses the app icon, you can use the NavUtils class's static method, navigateUpFromSameTask(). When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward. The way it is brought forward depends on whether the parent activity is able to handle an onNewIntent() call:
>
> If the parent activity has launch mode , or the up intent contains FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, the parent activity is brought to the top of the stack, and receives the intent through its onNewIntent() method.
>
> If the parent activity has launch mode , and the up intent does not contain FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, the parent activity is popped off the stack, and a new instance of that activity is created on top of the stack to receive the intent.

EDIT:

First add the parent activity to the manifest:

```
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Then call `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Edited to add code but the documentation has all the code you need

Answer (score 1):

You have to override **onBackpressed()** method and add PARENT_ACTIVITY meta-data in the Manifest file. Here is how to achieve this:

Add the below two lines in the Manifest file.

```
    <activity android:name=".activities.ChildActivity">
     <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
       android:value=".activities.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

And override the onBackpressed() method in ChildActivity:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed(){
 NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging I found the solution

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
     Log.v("back","pressed");
     return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

The code will be triggered every time you press the back button on the default support action bar.